# How to stop and start windows services in java on remote machine

Tags: java, windows-services

I have a java application that stops and starts windows services. I have a requirement that it should be able to do so on a **remote machine**. The current code I have for starting a Windows Service remotely looks as follows:

```
public void executeCommand() {

    String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/c", "sc", "\\\\192.168.1.27", "start", "btwdins"};
    try {
        Process process = new ProcessBuilder(command).start();
        InputStream inputStream = process.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println("Exception : " + ex);
    }
}
```

However when running this I get the following error:

```
[SC] OpenSCManager FAILED 5:

Access is denied.
```

Please note the following:

- Both local and remote machine are running on Windows 10
- The remote machine has it's firewall disabled
- RPC (Remote Procedure Call) is running on remote machine
- File and Printer sharing is turned on on remote machine

What am I missing? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might try adding the machine executing `sc.exe` into local `Administrators` group on the remote machine (how to do this depends heavily on the version of Windows you're using, so adding that to the question might help further answers to pop up).

Answer (score 0):

You can try downloading PsExec.exe from internet and write following code.

public class RemoteConnection
 {

```
 static String psCommandStart = null;
 static String psCommandStop = null;
public static void main(String[] args) {
      String currentServerHostname="192.168.0.1";
      String currentServerUser="Administrator";
      String currentServerPass="admin";
      String commandToStart="net start ServiceName";
      String commandToStop="net stop ServiceName";
      String psCommand = "D://Workspace //PsExec.exe \\\\"+ currentServerHostname + " -u " + currentServerUser + " -p " + currentServerPass;
      psCommandStart = psCommand + " " + commandToStart;
      psCommandStop = psCommand + " " + commandToStop;
      ServiceStart();
      ServiceStop();      

}

private static void ServiceStop() {
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
      cmd[0]="cmd.exe";
      cmd[1]="/C";
      cmd[2]=psCommandStop;
      cmd[3]="";
      cmd[4]="";
      // Run remote command
      File f = new File(getCurrentWorkingDirectory() + "\\lib");
      try 
      {
        Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,f);

      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 


}

private static void ServiceStart() {
    String[] cmd = new String[5];
      cmd[0]="cmd.exe";
      cmd[1]="/C";
      cmd[2]=psCommandStart;
      cmd[3]="";
      cmd[4]="";
      // Run remote command
      File f = new File(getCurrentWorkingDirectory() + "\\lib");
      try 
      {
        Process run = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd,null,f);
      } 
      catch (IOException e) 
      {
        e.printStackTrace();
      } 


}

private static String getCurrentWorkingDirectory() {
     String currentDir = System.getProperty("user.dir");
    return currentDir;
}
```

}